# Drawing arrows from certain nodes in a forest tree?

Tags: arrows, forest

How do I go about drawing arrows from the exposed right most nodes to my aligned values on the right.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
$$
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        l sep=2.5em
    }
     [$cn^2$
      [$c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
      ]
      [$c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
      ]
      [$c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
      ]
     ]
    \end{forest} &
    \quad\begin{aligned}
        &cn^2 \\ \\
        &\frac{3}{16}cn^2 \\ \\
        &\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^2cn^2 \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\
    \end{aligned}
  \end{array}
$$
\end{document}
```

This makes the following diagram:

[image]

But I would like to have something like:

[image]

I would also like to have the 3 equations on the right line up with the levels on the tree they correspond to.

Essentially I am trying to recreate diagram d) from my book:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `$$` for display maths in LaTeX.

Comment: Why not use $$ for display math nodes?

Comment: Most of the time, it will give you worse spacing than `\[...\]`, which was introduced a few decades ago with LaTeX 2e. There are some very unusual cases in which it might do worse, but the vast majority of the time, it will do better. There's a question about it somewhere if you search. (Of course, there's a question about most everything!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

[image]

i named the most right forest nodes and right of them positioned equations. then the draw of connection lines is simple:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        l sep=2.5em
    }
     [$cn^2$,name=L1
      [$c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
      ]
      [$c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
      ]
      [$c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2$, name=L2
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$
        []
        []
        []
       ]
       [$c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2$, name=L3
        []
        []
        []
       ]
      ]
     ]
    \node (a) [right=of L1 -| L3.east] {$cn^2$};
    \node (b) [right=of L2 -| L3.east] {$\frac{3}{16}cn^2$};
    \node (c) [right=of L3.east]       {$\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^2 cn^2$};
    \draw[dashed,->] (L1) -- (a);
    \draw[dashed,->] (L2) -- (b);
    \draw[dashed,->] (L3) -- (c);
    \end{forest}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also set a coordinate at `current bounding box.east` so it doesn't matter if the rightmost node changes (e.g. if the content of a node gets larger or smaller or whatever).

Comment: @cfr, i try this, but then the equation was not horizontally left aligned (i didn't manage to do this) .

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the `anchor` in this case, as you're using a coordinate for placement. At least, I think that's why ;).

Comment: Do you understand the pattern? I wanted to automate it, but I don't understand the pattern of the right-hand markers.

Comment: considering image provided by OP the code has error in last equation. correct is `$\left(\frac{3}{16}\right)^2n^2$`.

Comment: Yeah, that's just a typo on my part it should be 16 not 15

Comment: @Drew And it should have `c` also?

Comment: Yes there should be a c

Answer (score 3):

This code defines a `level markers` style for trees where you wish to mark levels and a `level mark` style for defining the mark. `level mark` can be added to any node on the relevant level. The code expects the value to require maths mode. (This would be easy to change if you need text.)

A new nodewalk step, `tier end` moves to the last node on the current `tier`. The `level markers` style sets up `tier`s to correspond to levels of the tree.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{
  define long step={tier end}{}{
    group={
      while nodewalk valid={next on tier}{next on tier},
      current
    }
  },
  level markers/.style={
    tikz+={
      \coordinate (tree marker) at ([xshift=10pt]current bounding box.east);
    },    
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        tier/.option=level,
      },
    },
  },
  level mark/.style={
    before drawing tree={
      for tier end={
        tikz+={
          \node (b) [anchor=mid west] at (tree marker |- .mid) {$#1$};
          \draw [densely dashed, -LaTeX] (.east) -- (b.west |- .center);
        },
      },
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    l sep=2.5em,
    math content,
  },
  level markers,
  [cn^2, level mark=cn^2
    [c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2, level mark=\frac{3}{16}cn^2
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2, level mark=\left(\frac{3}{15}\right)^2n^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
    [c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
    [c\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^2
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
      [c\left(\frac{n}{16}\right)^2
        []
        []
        []
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting tree]

## EDIT [In light of corrected level markers]

This code shows how to draw the tree automatically. It defines a style, `auto level markers` which takes 3 arguments: the number of children each parent has / numberator, the denominator and the number of levels to be filled and marked. For example, asking for 3 levels will yield a 4-level tree, where the fourth level consists of nodes without content and no level marker.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\forestset{
  define long step={tier end}{}{
    group={
      while nodewalk valid={next on tier}{next on tier},
      current
    }
  },
  level markers/.style={
    tikz+={
      \coordinate (tree marker) at ([xshift=10pt]current bounding box.east);
    },    
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        tier/.option=level,
      },
    },
  },
  level mark/.style={
    before drawing tree={
      for tier end={
        tikz+={
          \node (b) [anchor=mid west] at (tree marker |- .mid) {$#1$};
          \draw [densely dashed, -LaTeX] (.east) -- (b.west |- .center);
        },
      },
    },
  },
  declare count register={auto numerator},
  declare count register={auto denominator},
  declare count register={auto levels},
  declare count register={auto denominator squared},
  Autoforward register={auto denominator}{
    auto denominator squared=#1*#1,
  },
  auto numerator'=3,
  auto denominator'=4,
  auto levels'=3,
  auto level markers/.style n args=3{
    level markers,
    auto numerator=#1,
    auto denominator=#2,
    auto levels=#3,
    delay={
      tempcounta'=0,
      while={
        > RR< {tempcounta}{auto levels}
      }{
        where n children=0{
          repeat={
            >R{auto numerator}
          }{
            append={[]}
          }
        }{},
        do dynamics,
        tempcounta'+=1,
      }
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      where={
        > OR<  {level} {auto levels}
      }{
        if level=0{
          content=cn^2,
          math content
        }{
          content/.process={
            OR w2+P w {level} {auto denominator} {int(##2^##1)} { c\left(\frac{n}{##1}\right)^2 }
          },
          math content
        }
      }{},
      for nodewalk={
        r,
        while={
          > ORw+n< {level} {auto levels} {##1-1}
        }{l}
      }{
        if level>=2{
          level mark/.process={ O R R w3 {level} {auto numerator} {auto denominator squared} {\left(\frac{##2}{##3}\right)^{##1}cn^2} }
        }{
          if level=1{
            level mark/.process={ R R w2 {auto numerator} {auto denominator squared} {\frac{##1}{##2}cn^2} }
          }{
            level mark=cn^2
          }
        }
      },
    },
    before packing={
      for tree={
        l sep'=2.5em
      },
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  auto level markers={3}{4}{3},
  []
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  auto level markers={2}{6}{4},
  []
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The first tree is the corrected version of that drawn above:

[image: automated & corrected version]

The second randomly varies the values passed to the style, which may or may not make sense, given whatever the tree represents:

[image: variation]

Comment: Yeah, the missing c and 15 are typos, I'll fix EM. But, I am curious, how would I automate the structure of the tree? Since I am doing recurrences I will be doing this frequently.

Comment: @Drew See edit above. I guess you could simplify it further, by making a macro, but `\begin{forest}auto level markers={}{}{}[]\end{forest}` is the Forest bit. You can use `\newcommand` to create a convenience wrapper, if you want.

Comment: @Drew Basically, if there's a rule or pattern, Forest can apply the rule or pattern for you: whether it is the structure of the tree, the content of the nodes or additional annotation. This is handy if you need to do a lot of variations-on-a-theme :-).