# Copy the Merge sort recursion tree from tikz example with forest package

Tags: forest, trees, tikz-qtree

I'm trying to explain the execution time of an algorithm and I'm using the forest as a package to drawing tree, and with this post, I'm asking if is possible to draw the same tree in the figure below with the package forest. Form the forest [quick start](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/info/forest-quickstart/forest-quickstart.pdf) I don't see an example like that.

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code? Do you have code for `tikz-qtree` or something? (You've tagged the question with that.)  The answer to the question is: yes, you can do this with Forest.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302864/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/404588/, ... There are lots of examples on the site.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks :)

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo -- just stumbled across this exact replica at --- https://texample.net/tikz/examples/merge-sort-recursion-tree/  -- though not with forest 
 -- have alook below

Comment: unfortunately, I need to do this with the forest and not with tikzpicture

Comment: Why do you need to do it with `forest` particularly? `forest` is just a(n extremely sophisticated) wrapper around `tikzpicture`.

Comment: People are more likely to help with the tree if you provide the content of the nodes .... At least, I am. Too much work looking back and forth between editor and image.

Comment: @cfr I agree, but I open this post to collect some opinions, like yours in this subsection. I was able to use the documentation of tikzpicture to make the tree inside the question, but I was curious if was possible to use the forest. Why forest?, because I'm new with latex and I don't want to add unnecessary tools that I need to understand and learn in a small-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
% MergeSort-RecursionTree
% Manuel Kirsch
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{MergeSort-RecursionTree}
\author{Manuel Kirsch}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\ovalbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}[level/.style={sibling distance=60mm/#1}]
\node [circle,draw] (z){$n$}
  child {node [circle,draw] (a) {$\frac{n}{2}$}
    child {node [circle,draw] (b) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}
        child {node [circle,draw] (d) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
        child {node [circle,draw] (e) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
      } 
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
    child {node [circle,draw] (g) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
  }
  child {node [circle,draw] (j) {$\frac{n}{2}$}
    child {node [circle,draw] (k) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
      child {node {$\vdots$}}
    }
  child {node [circle,draw] (l) {$\frac{n}{2^2}$}
    child {node {$\vdots$}}
    child {node (c){$\vdots$}
      child {node [circle,draw] (o) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
      child {node [circle,draw] (p) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}
        child [grow=right] {node (q) {$=$} edge from parent[draw=none]
          child [grow=right] {node (q) {$O_{k = \lg n}(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
            child [grow=up] {node (r) {$\vdots$} edge from parent[draw=none]
              child [grow=up] {node (s) {$O_2(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
                child [grow=up] {node (t) {$O_1(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]
                  child [grow=up] {node (u) {$O_0(n)$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
                }
              }
            }
            child [grow=down] {node (v) {$O(n \cdot \lg n)$}edge from parent[draw=none]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
\path (a) -- (j) node [midway] {+};
\path (b) -- (g) node [midway] {+};
\path (k) -- (l) node [midway] {+};
\path (k) -- (g) node [midway] {+};
\path (d) -- (e) node [midway] {+};
\path (o) -- (p) node [midway] {+};
\path (o) -- (e) node (x) [midway] {$\cdots$}
  child [grow=down] {
    node (y) {$O\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^k 2^i \cdot \frac{n}{2^i}\right)$}
    edge from parent[draw=none]
  };
\path (q) -- (r) node [midway] {+};
\path (s) -- (r) node [midway] {+};
\path (s) -- (t) node [midway] {+};
\path (s) -- (l) node [midway] {=};
\path (t) -- (u) node [midway] {+};
\path (z) -- (u) node [midway] {=};
\path (j) -- (t) node [midway] {=};
\path (y) -- (x) node [midway] {$\Downarrow$};
\path (v) -- (y)
  node (w) [midway] {$O\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i = 0}^k n\right) = O(k \cdot n)$};
\path (q) -- (v) node [midway] {=};
\path (e) -- (x) node [midway] {+};
\path (o) -- (x) node [midway] {+};
\path (y) -- (w) node [midway] {$=$};
\path (v) -- (w) node [midway] {$\Leftrightarrow$};
\path (r) -- (c) node [midway] {$\cdots$};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I need to do this with the forest and not with tikzpicture, this doesn't answer at my question. Sorry

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo If this doesn't answer your question, you shouldn't accept it because fewer people will read your question if it is marked as answered.

Comment: I accepted this because the previous answer (now not longer exists), not answer me and propose another tool. for the moment is the only question try to answer me.