how to create trees like this in tikz? (or some other packages? and what libraries are the best?)
spesifically with the side arrows and their text


There are several questions demonstrating how to create similar trees using forest. What have you tried?

@cfr i couldn't find one with an easy implementation of those arrows and text to the side.

So post your code for the rest and ask somebody to add the arrows. There are some but finding things is a challenge.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404607/ labels the levels, for example.

Found one .... There are more, though. I've drawn more than the one there and I'm hardly alone. Just the search sucks. If you get stuck, post your code and explain the specific problem you're having. Once you have the level markers, adding the arrows is "simple" (!) TikZ because you've got the coordinates.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702157/ also has an arrow of the kind you want. Try searching for recursion tree and scroll down to answers.
